# Assign CSS class to <td> based on header info

Tags: css, html-table

Is there any way I can assign a css class to a table cell merely based on its header attribute?

The code is generated dynamically through a CMS so it's a little difficult to change, and it basically looks like this:

```
<td headers="blue">
```

How can I assign the style below to the td?

```
   {
      background-color: #1374bf;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the css attribute selector.

```
td[headers="blue"]{
    background-color: #1374bf;
}
```

Comment: [Another demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/083noy8u/1/) for if the headers attribute *contains* a string.

Comment: @showdev Thanks for that, I didn't know you could do that.